# Array members won't save

Tags: php

i learn php and stuck in trouble with next code:

```
    $people = new people();
    $people->getByNumber($value[0]);    
    $peoples = array();
    $count_people = 5;
    for($i=1; $i<=$count_people; $i++)
    {
        $people->getByNumber($i);
        $peoples[$i] = $people;
        print_r($peoples[$i]);
    }
    print_r($peoples);
```

so after cycle "for" `$peoples` dont show any information and `print_r` tell, that array consist of empty values (but keys exists). While cycle work, inside it `print_r` show me right pair key->value. How can i repair it to use right `$peoples` after cycle?

upd:
in for-loop by `print_r($peoples[$i]);` i can see that:

```
people Object
 (
    [id] =&gt; 1
    [age] =&gt; 19
    [short_name] =&gt; Jhon
    [full_name] =&gt; Jhon Persh
    [image] =&gt; 
 )
```

but after for-loop `$peoples` contains only:

```
Array
(
    [1] =&gt; people Object
        (
            [id] =&gt; 
        [age] =&gt; 
        [short_name] =&gt; 
        [full_name] =&gt; 
        [image] =&gt; 
        )

    [2] =&gt; people Object
        (
            [id] =&gt; 
        [age] =&gt; 
        [short_name] =&gt; 
        [full_name] =&gt; 
        [image] =&gt;  
        )

    [3] =&gt; people Object
        (
            [id] =&gt; 
        [age] =&gt; 
        [short_name] =&gt; 
        [full_name] =&gt; 
        [image] =&gt; 
        )

    [4] =&gt; people Object
        (
            [id] =&gt;
        [age] =&gt; 
        [short_name] =&gt; 
        [full_name] =&gt; 
        [image] =&gt;  
        )

    [5] =&gt; people Object
        (
          [id] =&gt; 
          [age] =&gt; 
          [short_name] =&gt; 
          [full_name] =&gt; 
          [image] =&gt; 
        )

)
```

upd2:

```
public function getByNumber($id)
    {
        $classProperty = get_object_vars($this);
        foreach ($classProperty as $key=>$value)
            $member[] = $key;

        $data = //random data generation;
        foreach ($member as $key =>$field)
        {
            $this->$field = $data[$field];
        }
    }
```

Comment: What keys exists in `peoples` after for-loop?

Comment: probably just a typo, but you have a square bracket before your closing paren ---> print_r($peoples]);

Comment: What does ```$people->getByNumber($i)``` do? Does it return a value and you want to add to the ```$peoples``` array?

Comment: `$people->getByNumber($i)` is a member function of class $people, it fill class fields such as age, name etc with random data.

Comment: need i declare array as array of `$people` elements as objects? if i need how to do it?

Comment: Can you add the people class? Or if it is too long, maybe just the getByNumber method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer in construcnt new object of class $people1 = new People(), then just use $peoples[] = $people1 in loop after call method getByNumber($id);
btw dont know why copy constructor dont call itself.

Answer (score 0):

In the for-loop you are setting `$peoples[$i]` to `$people`, but there is no variable called `$people`. You call `$people->getByNumber($i)` but don't save it anywhere.

Your for-loop should look something like this:

```
$p = $people->getByNumber($id);
$peoples[$i] = $p;
```

Comment: $people is an instance of "people" class, isn't it? $people = new people();

Comment: `print_r($p);` in this case dont show anything, and array `$peoples` after for-loop became array with keys from 1...5 and empty values

Comment: Is your function `getByNumber()` returning anything?

Comment: It doesn't appear to according to comments above, it adds values to the class properties.

Comment: `getByNumber()` only change information inside class. so in fact it the same object but with different information

Comment: From you comment it seems that the problem is in `getByNumber()`. It doesnt seem to assign any values.